# Understanding how the correct site gets served up to a domain?

Tags: dns, hosting, domain-name, nameservers

This question is sort of dev ops or networking related. When I point a domain at a hosting provider, I use a fairly generic Nameserver, i.e. `ns1.digitalocean.com`.

I understand when I add a domain to my hosting service to manage, that the hosting service recognises I am the registrant and serves up the site to the domain - so my question is, if another customer of the same hosting service adds my exact domain to manage on his account (there are now two) how does the correct registrant of the domain get selected? I.e. if there are two accounts on Digitalocean and they both put in `example.com` to manage and the registrar of `example.com` is pointing to the generic `ns1.digitalocean.com` how does Digitalocean select the correct accounut and code base to serve up? Apologies if any confusion or lack terminology - I am a bit fuzzy on this whole process. Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1):

They wouldn't allow another user to add the same domain, otherwise it's a bug.